# Indent of paragraph at enumerate package

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I'm confused to make this paragraph below using enumerate. Actually I don't know whether I could use the package or not. And I want this for certain paragraph only, but I have no idea to do it.

[image]

---

I did this manually with this script, Can somebody please help me to figure this out?

```
\noindent \textbf{A. INTRODUCTION}\\
\noindent \lipsum[1]
\noindent \textbf{\\B. METHODOLOGY}\\
\noindent \lipsum[1]
```

Comment: Do you really type section headings like this? *Please* consider using `\section` instead. And you may be looking for `\parindent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid what you're doing and move on to something better. Use `\section` instead of a manual enumeration or using a list. Your output resembles sectional units, so use them. Why? This leads to automated ToC, consistent spacing, no break between the title and subsequent paragraph content, a semantic coding style that matches the output as well as hooks into document elements that could be used in the future to adjust the presentation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\normalfont\bfseries\normalsize\MakeUppercase}% Change font for \section
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}% Change counter for \section
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.~}% Add period after \thesection (and others)
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Methodology}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```